# Camel Split InputStream by length not by token

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have an input file like this

```
1234AA11BB4321BS33XY...
```

and I want to split it into single messages like this

```
Message 1: 1234AA11BB
Message 2: 4321BS33XY
```

transform the records into Java objects, marshal them to xml with jaxb and aggregate about 1000 records in the outgoing Message.

Transformation and marshalling is no problem but I can't split the String above.
There is no delimiter but the length. Every Record is exactly 10 characters long. 
I was wondering if there is an out of the box solution like

```
split(body().tokenizeBySize(10)).streaming()
```

Since in reality each record consists of 300 characters and there may be 500.000 records in a file, I want to split an InputStream.

In other examples I saw custom iterators used for splitting but all of them where token or xml based.

Any idea?

By the way we are bound to Java 6 and camel 2.13.4

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to split by empty string - `.split().tokenize("", 10).streaming()` - meaning that tokenizer will take each character - and group 10 tokens (characters) together and then aggregate them into a single group e.g.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
  from("file:src/data?delay=3000&noop=true")
      .split().tokenize("", 10).streaming()
      .aggregate().constant(true) // all messages have the same correlator
        .aggregationStrategy(new GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy())
        .completionSize(1000)
        .completionTimeout(5000) // use a timeout or a predicate 
                                 // to know when to stop
      .process(new Processor() { // process the aggregate
        @Override
        public void process(final Exchange e) throws Exception {
          final List<Message> aggregatedMessages = 
            (List<Message>) e.getIn().getBody();
          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          for (Message message : aggregatedMessages) {
            builder.append(message.getBody()).append("-");
          }
          e.getIn().setBody(builder.toString());
        }
      })
      .log("Got ${body}")
      .delay(2000);
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's my memory consumption in streaming mode with 2s delay for a 100MB file:

[image: Memory consumption in streaming mode with 2s delay for 100MB file]

Comment: Hey thanks, this sounds promising. I will give it a try. split().tokenize("", 10) seems to be exactly what I want. It looks so easy why didn't I come up with this myself 

Comment: Tried it out. Now I get hundreds of megabytes of char[] Objects in memory, if I read a large file. I thought if I set e.g. split().tokenize("", 10) and completionSize(10) there will be 10 Strings of length 10 read from my file and routed through all of my routes. The next 10 Strings will be read from file not until the previous have been sent to the target system (well, left the last route). Regarding memory it makes no difference if I put the whole file content to a String or use the route above. It seems that tokenize puts the whole file content to char[] and does not stream.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you're not doing any additional processing before splitting? Because for me this piece of code does stream properly - it creates a `GroupTokenIterator` based around a `java.util.Scanner` which is buffered and streaming 8KB at a time. You will (and should), however, see a lot of `char[]`s in memory since Camel will instantiate a new array for each group and wait until 1000 groups have been collected, and GC will not trigger until memory is full.

Comment: To see if it's streaming properly, you could add a `.delay(5000)` step right after `.log()` step and open up jconsole and track memory consumption - you'll see that memory is being slowly filled instead of instantly.

Comment: Thank you, I get step high peeks in jconsole. I think it must be something else. I will analyze this...

Comment: You will get an almost instant peak without the delay since there's no real processing going on and you'll be seeing much more GC calls but that's about it.

Comment: OK thanks. By the way, could you please post your GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy. Maybe mine is misconfigured.

Comment: It's just a clone of https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/aggregate/GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy.java - it's present in newer Camel versions, though.

Comment: Any luck in tracking down the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I will post it here if I am successful. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score -1):

Why not let a normal java class do the splitting and refer to it? See here:
http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

Code example taken from the documentation.

The below java dsl uses the "method" to call the split method defined in a separate class.

```
from("direct:body")
        // here we use a POJO bean mySplitterBean to do the split of the payload
        .split().method("mySplitterBean", "splitBody")
```

Below you define your splitter and return each split message.

```
public class MySplitterBean {

    /**
     * The split body method returns something that is iteratable such as a java.util.List.
     *
     * @param body the payload of the incoming message
     * @return a list containing each part splitted
     */
    public List<String> splitBody(String body) {
        // since this is based on an unit test you can of cause
        // use different logic for splitting as Camel have out
        // of the box support for splitting a String based on comma
        // but this is for show and tell, since this is java code
        // you have the full power how you like to split your messages
        List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] parts = body.split(",");
        for (String part : parts) {
            answer.add(part);
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks I know this example but in splitBody(String body) the argument body would contain the whole file content. If I have a file with 500.000 records than these would be in the body argument and the array and the list would contain 500.000 items each. And I can't split by the "," token since the 10-character records aren't separated by commas. What I need is something like: Read 10 bytes of an InputStream, put them in a list. Do this until there are 1000 items in the list. Then put the List to the next endpoint in the route and start to fill the next list with 1000 items and so on.

Comment: So I never have the whole file in memory, only a small part.

Comment: convertBodyTo(String.class) or whatever format you want i.e. InputStream

Comment: Once you have it as stream then split it by any way you like, by length or some character.

Comment: Hm, doing it like this then the splitter Method will be called only one time. So I have to read in the whole file in this method and store the splitted Strings to the Message List. And therefore to memory. What I want to do is calling the split method while iterating over the InputStream. So I Need a custom Iterator like here http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/split-Iterator-streaming-td5078583.html. Maybe I should use 2 splitters. One to split the large file and one to cut out the 10-character Strings. The latter could work like you wrote in your First answer.

Comment: You can do it with two splitters but are you saying that whole file is one long line?

Comment: Yeah, it's a flat file with one line coming from a Mainframe. Milos approach sounds promising I will give it a try.